# how to return a Rails query as a hash with the keys as the primary key id value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm curious whether there is native way to return a query with the id value as the hash key returned. Something like:

```
Location.find([2,4,7]).as_hash
```

get back

```
{
  2:{name:"name 1", id: 2},
  4:{name:"name 4", id: 4},
  7:{name:"name 7", id: 7},

}
```

I'd like to just do a to_json and this would be convenient.

thx

Answer (score 0):

`I'd like to just do a to_json and this would be convenient.`

Natively, There is a `to_json` method which can directly give you the output of query in json format.

```
Location.find([2,4,7]).to_json
```

However, the format is different from what you have specified. Check if it works for you.

`to_xml, to_yaml` methods are other methods which can similarly output xml and yaml data, respectively, from the activerecord queries.

Alternatively, you can do something like this

```
locations = Location.find([2,4,7])
locations_hash = {}
locations.each do |location|
    locations_hash[location.id] = location 
end
locations_hash.to_json
```

Comment: thx, I currently do something like the latter. just seems kinda ugly esp since json api which is done by Rails core team members advocates something else.

Comment: Hmm, you can also do `json = {}.tap{ |h| Locations.each{ |l| h[l.id] = l}}.to_json` to do it all in one line, but that's not your concern, right?